How to show enum keys in OpenAPI?
I use EnumInt and want to show the enum keys at the OpenAPI docs.
from enum import IntFlag
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ResponseCode(IntFlag):
    request_failed: 1000
    request_success: 1001


class Response(BaseModel):
    success: bool
    message: str
    code: ResponseCode

But the the OpenAPI shows only:

I would like to show the keys and the values together.

That's how OpenAPI does enums - just the value, if you want a name or other metadata add a description.

The latest version of OpenAPI has a way to specify the names and descriptions for enum values, but I think FastAPI and Pydantic do not (yet?) support that OpenAPI syntax.
